# Blog broken after changing Site/Home URL

Tags: multisite, site-url, home-url

I have two blogs installed in the domain foo.com:

- foo.com
- foo.com/marketing

They different WP installations which share the same domain. Database tables from the `/marketing` installation use a proper prefix.

By misunderstanding, I changed the **Wordpress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** values in Settings:

[image]

I'm 90% sure the old values were the following: `http://foo.com/marketing`.

So I changed the values to some other one, realised that this breaks the blog, and changed back the values to `http://foo.com/marketing`.

However the pages remain broken - sometimes they are handled by the other blog, other times they return HTTP 500 because of too many redirects.

I tried setting `http://foo.com/marketing` everywhere advised - the database, `wp-config.php`, `functions.php`. Nothing worked.

There's the possibility that the `http://foo.com/marketing` value itself is somehow wrong, but the value seems ok to me.

What could I be missing? What solutions could I try?

Comment: Could you post the contents of the .htaccess files of both wordpress installations?

Comment: @Thomas here you go, thank you very much. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/294a047e61ef1f0a3296

Comment: It's better to [edit  your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/192960/edit) and paste in the `.htaccess` files' content, rather than linking somewhere off-site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the MySQL DB, make sure that wp_blogs.domain is correct, and also wp_blogs.path.

Also, run the following to verify the values are correct (assuming WP_OPTIONS is the table holding the options for your main site).

SELECT * from wp_options where option_name = 'siteurl' or option_name = 'home';